# Decoding only certain HTML tags in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I have to output the HTML which a user has entered with some formatting. I store the HTML in the database as it is, i.e. without encoding, as it's adviced [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx), but before showing it I encode it using MS AntiXSS library. However, I have to output some tags as HTML, e.g. make text bold or italic. What's the best approach to do that, while keeping the application safe from XSS? The idea I have is to first encode the text using AntiXssEncoder and then replace the allowed tags with the usual characters using RegExp. I know that some tools exist for it, like HTML Purifier, but I haven't found anything for ASP.

Update:
I've decided to use something like

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> allowedTags = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"&lt;p&gt;", "<p>"},
        {"&lt;/p&gt;", "</p>"},
        {"&lt;strong&gt;", "<strong>"},
        {"&lt;/strong&gt;", "</strong>"},
        {"&lt;em&gt;", "<em>"},
        {"&lt;/em&gt;", "</em>"},
        {"&amp;nbsp;", " "},
        {"&#13;&#10;", "<br>"}
    };
```

and then

```
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(item.Text, true));
        foreach (var tag in allowedTags)
        {
            text.Replace(tag.Key, tag.Value);
        }
```

Though I strongly dislike this solution since it lacks flexibility and I would have to manually insert each tag into the dictionary. Also, it doesn't support attributes, e.g. < p align="center" > would have to be a separate value. I guess I can replace the first part of the tag like

```
text.Replace("&lt;p", "<p");
```

However, if some tag is called, for example, padding (I don't know all HTMl tags which exist or might appear), then it would work with it too, since its beginning will be replaced, thus turning it into a valid tag (which might be not closed, though).

Comment: You can parse the input prior to saving, and remove the disallowed elements as early as possible. Preferably with a whitelist of allowed tags (the blacklist could potentially be rather big). You can use regex, but keep in mind that it might not be bulletproof. [Hacking stackoverflow.com's HTML sanitizer](http://danlec.com/blog/hacking-stackoverflow-com-s-html-sanitizer)

Comment: I cannot just remove them because it might be an element of the text; for instance, an author wants to write some HTML. I could have a code tag for it and clean everything but what's inside this tag, but I'm afraid that would be too complicated to implement for now.

Comment: Sure it can be part of the text, and that's not good at all, but nontheless you should have a strict policy for what elements you would allow (`<b>, <em>, <span>` (with or without inline styles), and which you wouldn't allow (e.g. `<script>` elements).

Comment: Yeah, my current solution does it. Microsoft AntiXssEncoder class already filters everything that might resemble HTML tag, so after filtering I transform allowed tags back so that they can be displayed as HTML. I'm still not quite satisfied with this approach, though.

Comment: Padding is attribute not a tag. If you preprocess the input properly to remove whitespace / scrub / etc then you can just use your current replacement algorithm as is and write it out as stored. I'd be doing all the work on POST not GET. Since you will likely GET many times more than you POST right?

Comment: I agree that encoding before storing in the database seems more efficient, however it's advised by MS to encode before the output. Since I am not very familiar with XSS, I preferred to follow their advice.

Comment: I don't mean encoding it, I just mean cleaning it up. Unless you can be absolutely sure that what get stored in the record won't be changed by any other means then, yes, you will need to encode on the way out.

Comment: Thanks, seems quite a nice idea, but I don't really know how to perform that clean up. Well, I guess I'm gonna use my current solution unless I come up with something better.